# How to get data from the web

Tags: python, html, database, web-scraping, text-mining

I want get data from specific web site. For example getting data about foods from various web sites. I want to get the web data with title, link, date and the time and the description. I hope to do this using machine learning. So is there specific methods to do this?(getting web data and filter by keywords).
Thanks

I tried using php. But I am not familiar  with the php.

Finally I want to publish those data in web site.

Comment: check topics like beautifulsoup or selenium

Comment: Is there a specific database to store those web data. That means the database that can work with the python?

Comment: but what exactly kind data you want store??

Comment: I want to store web links, related title, description, date that was published , time, author.

Comment: you can use mysql , sql server ..etc etc ..is enough

Comment: `"I hope to do this using machine learning."` The process of web scraping isn't machine learning. So I'm not sure what you mean by this. Also, what site are you specifically trying to get data from? Knowing how to store it is great, but you'd have to obtain the data first.

Comment: Yes, Can I know is there method to do get web data using machine learning? (Similar to the web scrapping)  I want to get web data related particular field.(for example let's take natural disaster news) Then I want to publish that data in my own web site automatically  without manually doing.